# Comparison and brace expansion

Tags: bash

Following is a simple shell script to demonstrate how environment variables are accessible.

```
if [[ ${x+X} = X ]] ## If $x is set
then
  if [[ -n $x ]] ## if $x is not empty
  then
    printf " \$x = %s\n" "$x"
  else
    printf " \$x is set but empty\n"
  fi
else
  printf " %s is not set\n" "\$x"
fi
```

However, I had the following doubts with regards to the first "if condition".

1. Inside the [[ operator a single "=" is used for comparison.But isn't = an assignment operator ?
2. Could you please explain "${x+X}" works in this script ?

Comment: Where did you get your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
{   unset x
    echo ${x+"you won't see this"}
    x=
    echo ${x+"this you'll see"} ${x:+"and this you won't"}
    x=1
    echo ${x+"now you'll"} ${x:+"see it all"}
}
```

---

```
this you'll see
now you'll see it all
```

---

Practically all of the basic POSIX parameter expansions behave differently when the expanded parameter is either unset or null depending on the `:` optional colon modifier.

The `+` form of parameter expansion expands to *`word`* when the parameter is set regardless of its contents in the expansion:

```
${parameter+word}
```

However, it does not expand to *`word`* when `$parameter` is set *but null* in the following:

```
${parameter:+word}
```

There are also the expansion forms for `-`, `=`, and `?`. The `-` will expand to *`word`* when `$parameter` is *unset*, or, with `:`, when it is either unset or null. The `=` will expand identically as `-`, except that it will also set the null or unset `$parameter`'s value to *`word`*. And `?` kills a shell while writing an optional *`word`* error message to stderr when `$parameter` is unset, or, with `:`, of null value. For any of these three, if the `$parameter` *is* set, and, with `:`, is not null, then `$parameter` expands to its value just as it would otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## Isn't = an assignment operator?

Yes, it is, and it is also a comparison operator, depending on where
it appears: as in many languages, meaning of tokens depends on
context. Bash supports both assignment, in the form `name=[value]`,
and comparison using the expressions languages for `test` (also known
as `[`) and `[[`; within those, `=` has a different meaning.

## What is `${x+X}`?

Bash supports the syntax `${parameter:+word}`:

> Use Alternate Value.  If `parameter` is null or unset, nothing is
>   substituted, otherwise the expansion of `word` is substituted.

In your case, this means that, if `x` is unset, then the expression
will expand to the empty string (the comparison with `X` will fail),
and, if it is set, it will expand to `X` (the comparison will yield
true).

The syntax `${parameter+word}` is a variation of `${parameter:+word}`,
with a slight difference, when `parameter` is set but empty:

```
x            ${x+alt}   ${x:+alt}
------------ ---------- ----------
unset                ''         ''
set to ''           alt         ''
non-empty           alt        alt
```

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted; is this answer incorrect?

Comment: yeah! what's obsolete? will you fix that please? also - i think i understand what you mean, and this part wasn't worth a downvote, probably - but can you clear up which is which when you refer to *first*?

Comment: I said "appears to be" obsolete because the versions without `:` are undocumented in my version of bash, so it's a fair guess that this version of bash consider that feature obsolete. I'd love to be corrected. Regarding the second point (see what I did there), while I agree that the wording in your answer is more explicit, I think mine is completely unambiguous. I'll edit to improve clarity.

Comment: id like to upvote it but the obsolete thing gets me. anyway, `man bash` says this *(and then lists each form explicitly)* under the heading EXPANSION and the subheading PARAMETERS: *When  not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below (e.g., `:-`), `bash` tests for a parameter that is unset or null.  Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.* - yours doesn't have that? Anyway, it's hardly authoritative.

Comment: @mikeserv: My copy of the GNU bash documentation does have the wording that you quote, which I had missed on a first read. I guess that makes it explicit that the feature is officially supported in that implementation.

Comment: Technically, there is no assignment operator. An assignment is a single string that contains an `=` and no surrounding whitespace; that's why `x=3` is an assignment statement but none of `x = 3`, `x= 3`, or `x =3` are.